# V8 profiling: linux-tick-processor not working with d8

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, javascript-engine

I'm trying to get the v8 profiling and linux-tick-processor working on my ubuntu.

Basically I have done these steps:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/v8/v8.git v8 && cd v8
$ make dependencie
$ make native
// added d8 to $PATH
$ d8 --prof primes.js
// v8.log is created
$ /home/username/v8/tools/linux-tick-processor
```

But it is not working, as a result i get:

```
Statistical profiling result from v8.log, (0 ticks, 0 unaccounted, 0 excludes).
```

So i assume the v8.log is not created correctly, because this result is stated with every other file you give the linux-tick-processor.
I checked the v8.log and it is created with some content:

http://pastebin.com/VLLWMKKM

For me it seems like it was generated correctly.

I tried profiling with node and this works:

```
$ node --prof primes.js
$ /home/username/v8/tools/linux-tick-processor
// correct output
```

But I want to use the d8 profiling.

Does someone has any idea or solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in V8.  I opened a bug report here:
http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2364